# How do I make Django form fields required conditionally?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am trying learn about creating web apps. I am trying to delete a record without the form fields being required. I only want them to be required when creating a new record. Here is a screen shot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPT3l.png)

Here is my form.py:

```
from django import forms

class ExpenseForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "Expense Name"
        })
    )
    amount = forms.DecimalField(
        max_digits=16,
        decimal_places=2,
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={
            "class": "form-control",
            "placeholder": "$400.00"
        })
    )
```

Here is my view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from budget.models import Expense
from .forms import ExpenseForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.db.models import Sum

def budget_view(request):
    expenses = Expense.objects.all()
    total = Expense.objects.aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))['total']

    form = ExpenseForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExpenseForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and 'create-expense' in request.POST:
            expense = Expense(
                name=form.cleaned_data["name"],
                amount=form.cleaned_data["amount"]
            )
            expense.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        elif form.is_valid() and 'edit-expense' in request.POST:

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

        else:
            expense = Expense.objects.get(id=request.POST.get("delete-expense"))
            expense.delete()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/') 

    context = {
        "form": form,
        "expenses": expenses,
        "total": total,
    }

    return render(request, "budget_view.html", context)
```

I tried adding `form.fields[<field_name>].required() = False` to the else block, but to no avail. Do I need to create a custom clean() in the form.py to perform validation on each field file or is there something else I can try.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`form.fields[<field_name>].required = False` is the right thing, except note that there are no parenthesis after `required`.

Also, I think it is a bit simpler to have the fields be optional by default and change them to required when needed.

Do this in the form's `__init__` method, something like:

```py
class ExpenseForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        required=False,
        ... # same
    )
    amount = forms.DecimalField(
        required=False,
        ... # same
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if "create-expense" in self.data or "edit-expense" in self.data:
            form.fields["name"].required = True
            form.fields["amount"].required = True
```

Comment: Hello @frnhr, I tried the __init__ method above, but I got this error: **'module' object is not subscriptable.** I changed `forms.fields` to `self.fields` which solved the problem, but now the form does not work correctly. When I try to create an expense, I need to click the create button twice for the validation to work. Why is this happening?